# Invisible Meshes

Tags: mesh

I have just started using Blender recently. 
When I add meshes they are invisible with exception to an orange outline around what would be the object. If I go into edit mode, the object appears with all the vertices selected. After I deselect the vertices and go back into the object mode, the mesh now appears. 
If I need to change some properties of the object, e.g. the number of segments, I have to do it while the object is invisible because going into edit mode will stop me from changing those properties.

Is there a way of ensuring that the object is added with all of its vertices deselected or some other solution to this issue?

Thank you!

Here are some screen shots of the problem:

[image: New Object]

[image: Object in Edit Mode 1]

[image: Object in Edit Mode 2]

[image: Object in Object Mode after Deselecting]

Comment: Hello :). This could be caused by unsupported hardware. Does it fullfill Blender's [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems that my hardware does not meet the minimum requirements. Is there any work-around or is it best to just upgrade the hardware?

Comment: Upgrading your hardware would be the best thing :). In the meantime, you can try some of Blender's [older versions](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/).

Comment: Cool, thank you!